# Multiple CSV to JSON file conversion

Tags: python, json, csv

I would like to convert csv to json in python.

My input file is like this:
[image]

and the output file should be like this:

```
{"translated_string":"¿Podrías buscar requisiciones de Editor Digital con habilidades de estrategia de clientes?",
  "skills":[{"skill":"estrategia de clientes",
     "startingPosition":67,
     "endingPosition":88}],
  "titles":[
   {"title":"Editor Digital",
     "startingPosition":33,
     "endingPosition":46}]}
```

Comment: read your csv into a dataframe and then use 'to_json' to convert it to json

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably less convoluted ways to do this, but this should work for the specific case outlined in the question.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from json import loads, dumps

filename = "example.csv"

col_names = ["translated_string", 
             "skill", "skill_startingPosition", "skill_endingPosition", 
             "title", "title_startingPosition", "title_endingPosition"]

df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0, names=col_names)

def create_dicts(x):
    return x.iloc[:,[1,2,3]].to_dict("records"), x.iloc[:,[4,5,6]].to_dict("records")

df = (df.groupby(["translated_string"])
        .apply(create_dicts)
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={0:"nested"})
      )
df[["skills", "titles"]] = pd.DataFrame(df["nested"].to_list(), index=df.index)

json_file = df.drop(columns=["nested"]).to_json(orient="records")
json_file = re.sub(r"(skill_|title_)\W*", "", json_file)
json_file = dumps(loads(json_file), indent=4)

with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json_file)
```